# fdisk - defaults to non Dos but yet uses Dos disklabel

Tags: partition, fdisk

My version of fdisk man page states default is DOS mode is disabled, which is what I want.... but why is it stating 'Created a new DOS disklabel'?

localhost four # fdisk /dev/sdc

Welcome to fdisk (util-linux 2.24.1). 
Changes will remain in memory only, until you decide to write them. 
Be careful before using the write command.

Device does not contain a recognized partition table.

Created a new DOS disklabel with disk identifier 0x780f1aa7.

Command (m for help):

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The "DOS mode" that the man page is referring to is a mode that keeps partitions aligned on cylinder boundaries, which have been an anachronism since the late 90's.  In other words, it defaults to letting partitions start and end on any sector.  The DOS disklabel, otherwise known as MBR, is the conventional PC partition table, as opposed to GPT, which is used in modern computers that boot using UEFI instead of bios, and is needed for drives > 2 TiB.